# Show accept certificate dialog with subclipse

Tags: eclipse, ssl, subclipse

I am working on an eclipse plug-in that uses the subclipse API to checkout and update some projects. In the case the SSL certificate on the server is not valid (expired), I want to show the confirmation dialog that subclipse also shows in this case (reject, accept temporary, accept permanently), but I can not find a way to do that.
Any ideas ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Network communications is handled by the Subversion API and it fires a callback that Subclipse implements to show the dialog.  We register the callback ([see JavaDocs](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/javahl/1.6/org/tigris/subversion/javahl/PromptUserPassword2.html))

I am not exactly sure what you want to do, but that is how Subclipse does it.  We register a callback before we call the API and then Subversion fires the callback when it needs to ask the user for credentials or to accept a certificate.